# How to prove that the solution is not global

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need help to prove the following question:
let  $y(t)>=0$ be in $C^1(0,T*)$ 
that satisfies  $$y'(t) > cy(t)^2-d$$ where $c$ and $d$ are both strictly positives constants.
I would like to show that T* is finite whenever
$$y(0)> \left( \frac{2d}{c}\right)^{1/2}.$$ 
In fact I can solve the problem when $d\le 0$ which is not the case here.

Comment: Perhaps you can show us your work for $d \le 0$ in case only small changes are needed for the case $d>0$.

Comment: if d<=0 we have $y'(t) >cy(t)^2−d> cy(t)^2$ we devide by $y(t)^2 $and the integrat between t and s then lelling t go to T* (the maximum time of existence) we obtain the result.

Comment: Does $t$ lie in $[0, \infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: t lies in $ [0,∞)$

Answer (score 0):

let $b = \frac{d}{c} > 0$, then we have
$$y'(t) > c y^2(t) - d = c \left( y^2(t) - b \right).$$
Let assume $y^2(t) - b > 0$. Then we have
$$\frac{y'(t)}{ y^2(t) - b } > c \implies \int_0^s \frac{y'(t)}{y^2(t)-b} \textrm{d}t > \int_0^s c \textrm{d}t = cs.$$
So we have by change of variables
$$ \int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{1}{t^2 -b } \textrm{d}t = \int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{1}{ \left(t - \sqrt{b} \right)\left(t + \sqrt{b} \right) }\textrm{d}t = \int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{A}{t - \sqrt{b} } \textrm{d}t + \int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{B}{t + \sqrt{b}} \textrm{d}t$$
Where $A$ and $B$ are such that $A+B= 0$ and $A-B = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$, so $A= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{b}}$ and $B= -A$.
Then we have
$$\int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{A}{t - \sqrt{b} } \textrm{d}t + \int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{B}{t + \sqrt{b}} \textrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}} \left( \ln \left( \frac{  y(s) -\sqrt{b}}{y(s) + \sqrt{b} } \right) - \ln \left( \frac{ y(0) - \sqrt{b}}{y(0) + \sqrt{b}} \right) \right).$$

So we find, denote the constant of the RHS by $\gamma$
$$ \ln \left( \frac{  y(s) -\sqrt{b}}{y(s) + \sqrt{b} } \right)  > \gamma + 2 \sqrt{b} c s.$$

The LHS is bounded as $s \to \infty$, but the RHS is unbounded and goes to $\infty$ as $s \to \infty$, so $y(s)$ is not defined for all $s \in [0, \infty)$.

Comment: the only thing that i didn't understand is why you add $\frac{i\pi}{2}$

Comment: la primitive de $1/(t^2−1)$ n'est pas $-tanh^(-1)(t)$ qui est toujours reelle?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $y(0) > \sqrt {\frac dc}$.

Since $y'$ is an increasing function of $y$, and $y'(0) > 0$, we can easily see that $y$ and $y'$ increase : we have $y'(t) \ge y'(0) > 0$ forall $t$, and so $y(t) \ge y(0) + y'(0)t$, which means that $y$ will have to take arbitrarily high values.

In particular, $y( \frac 1 {y'(0)} \sqrt {\frac dc}) \ge y(0) + \sqrt{\frac dc} > 2\sqrt{\frac dc}$.

From this point on, you have $y > 2 \sqrt {\frac dc}$, hence $-d > -\frac 14 cy^2$, and so $y' > \frac 34 cy^2$.

But the solutions to $y' = \frac 34 cy^2$ are of the form $y(t) = - \frac 4{3c(t-t_0)}$, and those blow up in finite time from some $y>0$. More precisely, it blows up in time $\frac 2{3\sqrt{cd}}$ from a point at $y = 2\sqrt {\frac dc}$ .

This shows that the solution to your original equation has to blow up before $t = \frac 1 {y'(0)} \sqrt {\frac dc} +\frac 2{3\sqrt{cd}} < \frac 1 {cy(0)^2-d} \sqrt {\frac dc} + \frac 2{3\sqrt{cd}}$